# NSDate returns nil for 1933-01-01 00:00:00 in Singapore local time (SGT)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, datetime, timezone

If you run this code you can see that the NSDate is always null for the 1933-01-01 00:00:00 +0000. Please help me how to resolve it.

```
NSString *date = @"1933-01-01 00:00:00 +0000";

 NSString* dateString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", date] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" +0000" withString:@""];
        NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"SGT"]];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
        [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
        [dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
        NSDate* sgtDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
        NSLog(@"SGT Date: %@",sgtDate);
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is working for me.

Comment: I am in Singapore and I am getting null for the above code @rebello95

Comment: whats the work around for this Im clueless @user2864740

Comment: It may be related to [when the time (zone) *jumped ahead* by 20 minutes at the start of 1933](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/aslaksen/teaching/timezone.html) - Does it work for  `1933-01-01 00:21:00 +0000` (that is, 21 minutes past the hour)?

Comment: yeah I even got to know about but it seems the issue is not only with 1933. How to resolve this any idea > can you pass this question around @user2864740

Comment: @user2864740 1933-01-01 00:21:00 +0000 - yes it works

Comment: @Ashan Ahh, then it's explained (also the code strips off the UTC offset and loads the date in the local/Singapore TZ). The first 20 minutes of 1933 (in the historical Singapore local time) just don't exist. However, I have no idea how to handle this sort of situation gracefully. (Using the time entirely in UTC would avoid the local TZ rule issues and it would still parse as a value UTC datetime.)

Comment: so what can i do for that :P @user2864740

Comment: @Ashan Now that the problem is identified it may be worthwhile to expand the problem description and assertions - that leaves the core problem: "How to deal with local times that do not exist due to historical timezone rule changes?" In this case, since the time jumped forward, it may be most appropriate to *subtract* the difference (20 minutes) from the non-existent local time. This would result in an existing local time with a valid transformation back to UTC.

Comment: @Ashan Alternatively the issue may be related to trying to shoehorn a TZ onto a datetime without a TZ offset or TZ (and valid time in such a TZ). Consider that "1933-01-01 00:05:00 +0700" *is* still a valid time (although it is not "1933-01-01 00:05:00 SGT"); then see what such a time+offset converts into when applying a local TZ.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT+08:00"]];
```

Instead of

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"SGT"]];
```

Comment: what's the output you're expecting?